# replace packages in java library with storm

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm new to storm and java 
i imported java project using old version of storm as library but i want to use another version of storm so i should delete any packages of old storm for this project ! right ?

where can i find it?

i guess it's on the `/user/.m2/repository/storm/....` i should delete storm folder on repository ? ! only or is there another thing i should do it ?

what are packages of new version of storm i should put it instead of packages of old version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `maven` project, you will have `pom.xml` in your project root folder.

In `pom.xml`, you will find all the dependencies in `<dependencies>...</dependencies>`
section where you will find the dependency for `apache-storm` as well with a `version`.

For the new version, you can look up in [mvn repository](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=apache%20storm) and simply change the `<version>` in your `dependency`.

If you select any result, you will get the list of all available versions.

The path your are referring to is the maven local repository and you do not need to manually delete any of the folders. Just changing the `dependency version` in your `pom.xml` is sufficient.

Comment: thanks , yes it's maven project and found the dependencies section in pom , ok now i'll change version of storm there , and download from url the files for my new version only that what i should do ? and if i did that , /.m2/repository / should changed successfully for what i want ? right ?

Comment: Once you change the version, you should  build(`mvn clean install`) the project. In that process it will download the new dependencies and will copy to your local repository. No need to manually add the packages/jar's..etc to your local repository /user/.m2/repository/storm....

Comment: And no need to download the files. Just look at the available versions in mvn repository  and then change the version in your pom.xml and then mvn clean install the project. That's it!